# How to add the muliple date in the combox box

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Using Asp.Net and Java Script

from Datatime control i am picking mulitple data which should add the combo box.

Java Script

```
function closed(cal) {
    $("#txtIndividualDays").val("");
    var noDays = 0;
    var ddlDate = document.getElementById("sIndividualDays");
    var opt;
    ddlDate.options.length = 0;

    MA.length = 0;

    var countDays = 0;
    for (var i in cal.multiple) {
        countDays++;
    }
    var arrDays = new Array(countDays);
    countDays = 0;
    if (arrDays.length == 0) {
        opt.text = "Select Date";
        opt.value = "-1";
        $("#txtIndividualDays").val($("#txtIndividualDays").val() + opt.text + ";");
    }
    for (var i in cal.multiple) {
        arrDays[countDays] = i;
        countDays++;
    }
    for (var i in arrDays.sort()) {
        var d = cal.multiple[arrDays[i]];
        var isWeekend = false;
        var isHoliday = false;
        if (d) {
            var _date;
            _date = d.print("%m/%d/%Y");
            opt.text = d.print("%m/%d/%Y");
            opt.value = d.print("%m/%d/%Y");
            MA[MA.length] = d;
            document.getElementById("txtIndividualDays").value += opt.text + ";";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("txtWorkingDays").value = noDays;
    var control = $("#sIndividualDays");
    var itemCount = $("#sIndividualDays option").length;
    cal.hide();
    return true;
};
```

The above script is showing error, while selecting a single date.  What wrong in my script.
Need scrip help

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that these lines are correct:

```
var opt;
..............
opt.text = "Select Date";
opt.value = "-1";
...........
```

I suggest you change to: `var opt = new Object();`